# Full screen mode in iFrame

Tags: html, iframe, fullscreen

I have a HTML with an iFrame where the source is another HTML. I would like to include a "full screen button" on the embedded HTML, so that if I click on it, that HTML becomes full screen.

In other words, I would like to do the same thing that Youtube does with a video that is embedded in a HTML, when you click on the "full screen button".

How can I do that?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik the easiest way to have real full screen would be through Flash. So what you could do is make that "full screen button" a flash player that pulls your HTML content and presents it full screen.

Here's a starting point for flash's full screen mode:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html

update: There is also a full screen API for browsers – like this one at mozilla – but that would depend on client side compatibility:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FUsing_full-screen_mode

PS: of course also flash requires client side compatibility..:)